# Redis dump.rdb | not default directory

Tags: redis, selinux

Sorry if this is a repeat question, but I have searched stackoverflow for hours and could not find the answer.

Scenario:

I changed the default directory of Redis's dump.rdb because my employer wanted it in a specific directory. I edited the line in the redis.conf file dir so that it points to /www/redis/sessions. I didn't change the file name, so it is still dump.rdb. I also have it running as a service in the /lib/systemd/system. I am using redis v4.0.11 if that helps.

Problem:

When I go to stop the daemon with systemctl stop redis. I get an error from SELinux saying that redis-server does not have permission to write in /www/redis/sessions. It also attempts to create a temp file with the name temp-####.rdb rather than trying to open the dump.rdb. I checked the directory and file permissions and made sure that any user could write to it. I still get the same error.

Tried:
 1. Adding the line ReadWriteDirectories = /www/redis/sessions in the service file in systemd.
 2. Changing the /www/redis/sessions directory so that anyone can write to it.
 3. Changed the dir in redis.conf file to /www/redis/sessions
 4. Checked the redis instance is loading the correct redis.conf file with the ./redis-cli CONFIG GET *
 5. Added the suggested local policy recommended by SELinux
 6. Changing the content of the redis-server with chcon -R --type=httpd_sys_content /www/redis/sessions & chcon -R --type=httpd_sys_rw_content_t /www/redis/sessions

Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SELinux works with policies that are distinct from the access rights edited with `chmod` etc. You won't get much help without posting your policy. As a wild guess, I'd say redis' create mask is wrong.

The `temp-####.rdb` files are not an issue. Redis write to temporary files first, then moves them to the final destination. It's a typical method to preserve the existing file when the write fails.

Have you considered leaving the .rdb where it is, and simply linking it in the location your micromanaging boss wants it?